# How to change background color for each menu item in NavigationDrawer material design?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, material-design

I use this design layout for `NavigationDrawer` and commun material design `menu.xml` but I cannot find a way to make each line of menuitem in different color. How to do it?

Here's my navigation drawer xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:itemIconTint="#333"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you just post code, what you have tried?

Comment: * Refer http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

Comment: well i have try to create navigationmenu programetically and and try to select menu item but did not find any property of menuitem that set background color #Nigam Patro

Comment: can you please post you menu file where you have defined your menu ?

Comment: So, you have created row item layout to use as menu?

Comment: well there is a way to do app:action_layout in appcompect but to inflate each seprate raw is not good idea for programming ..so i am getting stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it isn't straightforward to do what you are upto. If you wan't such type of customisation for Navigation drawer, it would be better if you provide your entire view inside NavigationView and then you can style it in whichever way you want.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            ...

       </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Now, you can create your menu view inside this linear layout as the way you want. I hope this helps you..

Comment: oh yes it is the best way to Customize menu i see it after long time Sorry i forgot to select your answer ,yaa it was helpful to me for custom me Thank u @yash Ladia.

Answer (score 0):

use compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_navigation"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_view_item_background"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_text_color"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_navigation_drawer" />
```

uses to the following XML file for item backgroud: nav_view_item_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

uses to the following XML file for Text Color: nav_item_text_color

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@android:color/black" />
```